# Networking issue connecting cat6 cables

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

I put a cat6 cable between 2 rooms in my house. I've added the connectors on the cable, and the cable itself works (when I connect computers on both sides, the network status goes from 'Not connected' to 'No internet').

Unfortunately, the cat6 cable is too short, so I put an inline coupler and a second (1 meter) cat6 cable. The second cat6 cable works as well (I tested it in the same way).

When I connect the 2 cat6 cables with the inline coupler between, I can't get a solid connection. My computer keeps showing 'Not connected'. If I try to 'wiggle' the cable a bit, it sometimes (briefly) goes to 'No internet'.

Additional information:

1. I wired the cables according to  T568B.
2. I noticed that the inline coupler they gave me at the store is
   actually not cat6, but cat6a.

What can I do to solve this issue (and replacing the cat6 wire between the rooms is not an option)? Or what is causing this issue?

Edit: update -- replacing the inline coupler with a switch gives me a working connection (I just still don't know why the coupler doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

"No Internet" implies a good physical connection, likely even a successful connection with traffic, so you may well be done with the cabling part.

No Internet typically means that while there is a network connection, there is no path (yet) discovered to the Internet as defined by the OS (likely there is an Internet host it expects to be able to connect to, and is not).  You may have a routing issue, or you may have simply connected two computers without connecting to the Internet in the first place.

Try to trace a line with your finger from the computer with this error, along the network cables and devices, to the cable that leaves your house with the network traffic.  You should be able to do this without lifting your finger off of them. (obviously the cable through the wall makes that a little harder, and I'm assuming you don't have a wireless link in the mix).

Comment: This is not what is happening. As mentioned: "When I connect the 2 cat6 cables with the inline coupler between, I can't get a solid connection. My computer keeps showing 'Not connected'. If I try to 'wiggle' the cable a bit, it sometimes (briefly) goes to 'No internet'.".

Comment: I also (just) tried replacing the inline coupler with a switch and everything worked fine in that case. I just don't know why...

Comment: How far apart are these rooms?  There are cable length requirements, and if you've exceeded them, you would get the behavior you describe (including the problem going away if you replace a coupler with a switch)

Comment: The cable length is between 10 and 15 meters.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed something about the coupler: the place to put in the connector on one side is upside down. Could this be related to straight vs crossover wiring? As mentioned, I put each connector on the cable in the same way, according to  T568B. Edit: that doesn't explain the connection sometimes working briefly though.